# Checkbox issue oncheck function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, web-component

Please see the following code at first. 
I want the particular checkbox (with id **cfc1**) to not be shown ticked whenever clicking on it.
I have used the `onCheck` function there. I'm not finding any way to the particular element be shown unchecked whenever clicked on it. I'm trying using the code -

```
if(e.currentTarget.id === 'cfc1') {
    document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id).checked = false; 
}
```

but it's not working.

How to do it using the `onCheck` function?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';

class Checkboxes extends Component {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
        checkids:['cfc0', 'cfc1', 'cfc2', 'cfc3']
     };
     this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
     this.getElements = this.getElements.bind(this);
  }
  getElements() {
     let arr = [];
     this.state.checkids.forEach(function(element) {
        arr.push(
          <Checkbox
             id={element}
             onCheck={this.handleCheck}
          />
        );
     }, this)
     return arr;
  }
  handleCheck(e) {
     console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
     console.log(e.currentTarget.checked);
  }
  render() {
     return(
       <div>
          {this.getElements()}
       </div>
     );
  }
}
export default Checkboxes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working for your use case, try having a state variable that maintains the checked information of each element id.

And in the `onCheck` handler toggle the checkbox for all the boxes except the one desired by setting the state.

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-ui-checkbox)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
     this.state = {
        checkids:{
          'cfc0': false,
          'cfc1': false, 
          'cfc2': false,
          'cfc3': false
        }
     };
  }

  handleCheck(e) {
     const checkids = {...this.state.checkids};
     checkids[e.target.id] = e.target.id === "cfc1" ? false : !checkids[e.target.id];

     this.setState({checkids});
  }

  getElements() {
     let arr = [];
     Object.keys(this.state.checkids).forEach(function(element, index) {
        arr.push(
          <Checkbox
             key={index}
             id={element}
             checked={this.state.checkids[element]}
             onCheck={this.handleCheck.bind(this)}
          />
        );
     }, this)
     return arr;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          {this.getElements()}
       </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I have edited my question a little. how to do it using the onCheck function ?

Comment: I'm trying using this code inside the handleCheck function. but it's not working. - if(e.currentTarget.id === 'cfc1') { document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id).checked = false; }

Comment: That won't work, because the first time it executes it checks it. I will add an update soon but what is your use case that is requiring you to only do it in the `onCheck` handler?

Comment: yeah. Thanks for your concern friend. That's why just now I have edited the question again. I'm actually having this kind of issue.

Comment: Updated the answer, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.checked = false` via javascript

```js
document.getElementById('cfc1').onclick = function() {
  this.checked = false;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cfc1">Click</label>
```

Comment: Can you do this thing by using the onCheck function event handlers?

Comment: I'm trying using this code inside the handleCheck function. but it's not working. -  if(e.currentTarget.id === 'cfc1') {
   document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id).checked = false;
  }